# When is `.env` defined variables are used on Next.js Applications?

Tags: javascript, next.js, environment-variables

When using Next.js to create web application, we can use environment variable files like `.env.development` and `.env.production`. And fill it with env variables like below;

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT="https://some.api.url/api"
```

And my question is **"When are these variables used?"**

When I build next.js application with `next build`, it prompts:

```
> next build

info  - Loaded env from ~/project/folder/.env.production
info  - Loaded env from ~/project/folder/.env
```

And When I serve build result with `next start` :

```
> next start

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from ~/project/folder/.env.production
info  - Loaded env from ~/project/folder/.env
```

So this means env is loaded on build-time, and run-time.

But there must be one time where ENV variables are loaded and used.

When is these variables defined in the env file are used?

Answer (score 1):

Because there may be access to these variables both at build-time AND at runtime.

For example:

- Your build will use them to create built outputs, like static code
- At runtime your code may require in-process access to them, like for handling server-side requests